# UITableView not reloading data when not visible?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm puzzled with this.
I have a UIScrollView and inside I have placed 4 tableViews.

The whole thing is used to allow scrolling horizontally and switching tableViews like the Groupon app.

As soon as you start scrolling the 4th (left or right) tableView, is moved in the scrollView and a reloadData is initiated on that tableView, so it will load the data from the datasource for that category.

However, when I scroll into that tableView, it still has the data from the previous category, meaning the cell's didn't get refreshed.

Can anyone shed a light on why this is happening?

I'm guessing only that because the tableView is not in a visible frame when I call the reloadData command, actual drawing is not happening in the tableView (the datasource methods are being called normally, but no drawing is happening).

Any ideas, or tips ?

Comment: Can you post some code or image to get better understanding of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, this is not code related. It's a question if the UITableView does redraw or not if it's outside the visible portion of the view.